# MS Access 2010 Object Passing Value instead of Reference ... Sometimes

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a small bit of code for a much larger MS Access database that likes to behave erratically. I can't say for sure, but it seems to change when I compile or recompile the database. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub FindCtls()

Dim DatType as String
Dim thisCTL as Control

DatType = Right(ActiveControl.Name, Len(ActiveControl.Name)-4)

For Each thisCTL In Me.Controls
   If InStr(1, thisCTL.Name, DatType, 2) > 0 Then
     Select Case Left(ThisCtl.Name,4)
       Case "Sel_"
           Set TgtCtls(0) = thisCTL
       ' A buncha other Cases
     End Select
  End If
Next thisCTL

End Sub
```

The problem is, when I step through the code, for some reason thisCTL is being passed as the value of the control, not the control itself. I've looked everywhere for this answer, that brought me to using the "Set" command instead of just putting TgtCtls(0) = thisCTL. That worked until I decompiled the DB and recompiled it. Made one change (changed the name of the first variable), compiled it again, and it worked. As I got into work today, someone told me that it was no longer working. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I forgot to mention that TgtCtls is a form-wide array that was Dim'd at the top as such:

```
Option Compare Database
Dim TgtCtls(2) as Control
```

Comment: What do you mean when they say "it's not working". The value is probably the default property for the control. Why are you thinking it's not working - it looks like you're referencing all the properties of ThisCtl

Comment: What I mean by that is the user's informed me that there was a problem, and I have deduced it down to this. The problem is that when I try to reference any property of TgtCtl it says there is no object. I did find a work around in changing it from a sub to a function, but now this has turned into more of a theoretical question as to why I was getting the variables passed as values instead of reference.